# Why i see the golden glow of sunlight on green leaf during evening although an object absorb all the colour and reflect a particular colour light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering, vision

Today I notice very weird (for me) phenomenon, I was in open in evening in a garden , and looking at leaves of trees around me.

1.I see a yellowish glow of sunlight on it along with green colour of leaves.

But I have learnt that when sunlight fall on a colored object, every wavelength colour in spectrum of sunlight got absorbed by object and reflect only that wavelength colour of which colour object is! Example  If I have a red ball , sunlight falling on it , every other colour from sunlight got absorb except red, which reflect into eye help us to identify colour of ball.

So if trees leaves are green  ,and in evening sunlight is little yellowish(due to absenceof blue colour because if scattered away) , according to Me all colour should get absorb by green leaves except green  so only colour from leaves visible should be green.

But there was a golden glow how, does sunlight reflect from rough leaf!

2   Same I notice with a red bulb on my ceiling it is making a rough concrete wall behind glowing red, but wall is black is colour. Again same doubt "if a particular colour object the all colour lights from spectrum from source except the one whose colour object is , than that black wall should absorb red colour . Glow should be visible only If light reflects from it  , but that wall is black in colour , why it doesn't absorb red light from bulb . Same even if wall is green , pink etc. All the wavelength light  should be absorb except the object's 'colour' one!

Please explain where I am having misconception?

Look

[image]

See here Apple and leaf absorb blue colour because it doesn'tmatch to apple colour.
Shouldn't the black wall(or any colour) should absorb red light from bulb

Comment: I have seen this very thing happen before too. Mostly in AZ in the eveni ng sun with a strong golden sunset. The pine trees along the hwy that are dead absorb the golden sun light and look very golden.

Answer (score 3):

> But I have learnt that when sunlight fall on a colored object, every wavelength colour in spectrum of sunlight got absorbed by object and reflect only that wavelength colour of which colour object is

This is a simplified explanation. Note that green leaves don't have a *saturated* green color. They are rather pale. This means that some of the non-green parts of the spectrum are also reflected, washing out the pure green to more natural color, as well as letting you see the spot of sunlight.

The exact color may be given by a reflectance spectrum. See a sample reflectance spectrum of a green leaf below (image [source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242345848_Introduction_to_Protein_Absorption_Lines_Index_for_Relative_Assessment_of_Green_Leaves_Protein_Content_Using_EO-1_Hyperion_Datasets)). The chlorophyll absorption peaks result in the reduction of reflectance at roughly $450\,\mathrm{nm}$ (blue) and $650\,\mathrm{nm}$ (red), and this is what gives you green color. But the absorption is far from complete, which reduces color saturation.

[image]

Comment: But ,in noon also this means some of the sunlight is reflected back ....but we don't notice it , simply we see a green color leaf. But as in morning or sunset when light is reddish yellow , we start seeing a golden patch. So why don't in noon  we see white patches ? And only green color of leaf?

Comment: @SureshChandraPal that's because of [chromatic adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_adaptation).

Comment: What do u mean ,can u pls explainsir?

Comment: When the sky, as in the morning or evening, is the main contributor to illuminance, our eyes&brain adapt to the blue illuminant, so the orange/golden patches of direct sunlight look high-contrast orange. With direct sunlight or moonlight, Sun & Moon dominate, so we adapt to their (white) colors. The leaf colors are evaluated with respect to the dominating illuminant, and when there are no "unusual" light patches on the leaves, the color looks green.

Comment: So that mean we are adapted to white colour, in noon along with green ,some  sun rays are reflected by leaf, but we don't notice it and green colour of leaf dominate over white patches of direct rays. Although in evening there is some unusual 'colored rays like golden or orange that attracts and seem new to eye and hence it is noticed along with green color if leaf. Overall....U mean along with respective color of colored object, some amount of other colors(not that of object) is also reflected?

Comment: @SureshChandraPal you should make a clear distinction between color and frequency. The color of an object is composed of a lot of frequencies in different proportions. A green object will have more reflectance in the green range of the spectrum, but may have nonzero reflectance in other parts of the spectrum. In particular, if you look through a red filter at a leave lying on a wet soil, you'll see that the leave is brighter than the soil. This must mean that some red is reflected from the leave, so not all of it is absorbed.

Comment: So that I am saying sir, that in noon or white light time from sun, there is reflectance of other color too from leaf other than green  but in a much small amount  compared to green, in noon other than green , other color of spectrum reflect but all of them 'almost' small amount and equal amount but green  in high amount , thus dominating and other colors of spectrum doesnt notice. But during evening green is reflected but along with it orange (left most in spectrum due to scattering) reflected and orange color (along with much green) I absence of other bluish color of spectrum creat....

Comment: Create a illuminance of yellowish patch over 'green'(still dominating) color of leaf, isn't it ? If I am wrong suggest me topics I have to learn sir to know about it?

Comment: @SureshChandraPal that's basically right. In the evening sunlight has much smaller amount of blue, and somewhat smaller amount of green, so you get a noticeable tint of orange in the reflected light. I.e. if at noon you get "small blue, large green, small red", then in the evening the reflected light is "almost no blue, some green, some red", and this looks like orange.

Comment: OK thank u , this answer increase my knowledge

Answer (score 2):

This is grazing incidence scattering. For perpendicular incidence predominantly green light is reflected. For grazing incidence all colors are reflected, as in the case of the air-glass interface. The reflectivity limit is unity independent of polarisation and color. [image: Fresnel reflectance/transmittance for air to glass]

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations#Power_(intensity)_reflection_and_transmission_coefficients

Comment: Can u please elaborate it more? In a easy way , I m just a student I haven't study these in deep!